# Given string and (list) of words, return words that contain string (optimal algorithm)

Tags: python, regex

Let's say we have a list of unique words and a substring.

I am looking for an optimal algorithm, that returns words containing the substring.

The general application is: Given a database use search bar to filter the results.

A simple implementation in Python:

```
def search_bar(words, substring):
    ret = []
    for word in words:
        if substring in word:
            ret.append(word)
    return ret

words = ["abc", "bcd", "thon", "Python"]
substring = "on"

search_bar(words, substring)
```

this would return:

`["thon", "Python"]`

in time `O(lenght_of_list * complexity_of_in)`, where *complexity_of_in* depends in some way on the length of the substring and the length of individual words.

What I am asking is whether there is faster implementation. Given that we can preprocess the list into any structure we want.

Just redirection to the problem/answer would be amazing.

*Note:* It would be better if such structure doesn't take too long to add a new word. But primarily it doesn't have to be able to add anything, as the Python example doesn't.

Also, I am not sure about the tags with this question...

Answer (score 0):

maybe use

```
word.find(substring)
```

instead

```
substring in word
```

and as variant:

```
def search_bar(words, substring):
    return list(filter(lambda word: word.find(substring)!=-1, words))
```